# Google Secure Apps

Tags: php, google-apps-script, smtp, gmail, imap

I've been using a PHP script to access Google's SMTP and IMAP so that emails sent from the script page are copied to the client's Gmail sent items. However Google has now locked down and locked out "insecure apps" which also seems to lock out my script, no matter which settings I change in Gsuite or the gmail account. How would I make it a "secure app" given that the usual app password approach seems inapplicable, since the device is a web server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Securing your App would consist on using the more secure OAuth2 protocol to make requests to the Gmail API or authenticate to the SMTP or IMAP.

Using the Gmail API is more user friendly and for your use case I think it's more indicated. You can start building a Gmail App using these [tutorials](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides).

Read these articles to know more about OAuth on Gmail Apps:

- [IMAP/SMTP](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol)
- [Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2)

Comment: This is a FULL implementation of standard PHP IMAP functions like (imap_open, imap_getmailboxes, imap_*, etc...) https://github.com/ddeboer/imap/issues/443#issuecomment-1172158902 @Alessandro